# Using async/await for promise-based APIs in UI5

Tags: javascript, async-await, sapui5, ui5-tooling

The official UI5 documentation [proposes](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/19453962b8074b7399372c65cbe05370) to load a `Fragment` using promises:

```js
Fragment.load({
    controller: oFragmentController,
        id: oView.getId(),
        name: "webapp.view.HelloDialog"
    }).then((oDialog) => {

    oView.addDependent(oDialog);

    oDialog.open();

});
```

I personally would prefer to use `async`/`await` instead:

```js
const oDialog = await Fragment.load({
    controller: oFragmentController,
    id: oView.getId(),
    name: "webapp.view.HelloDialog"
});

oView.addDependent(oDialog);

oDialog.open();
```

How save would be such code refactoring and transition from `.then`-promises to `async`/`await` in UI5? Can it lead to some issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can <del>safely</del> use `async`‑`await` in UI5 <del>since it's basically syntactic sugar for Promise</del> **with some restrictions currently.** *****

Given `<Dialog id="helloDialog">` in the fragment definition, and `this` being the current controller instance, creating the fragment would then look like this:

#### With [`this.loadFragment` (since UI5 1.93)](https://sdk.openui5.org/nightly/#/api/sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller%23methods/loadFragment)

```js
// this === Controller instance
onOpenDialog: async function() {
  const dialog = this.byId("helloDialog") || await this.loadFragment({
    name: "webapp.view.HelloDialog"
  });
  dialog.open();
},
```

#### With `Fragment.load` (since UI5 1.58)

```js
// this === Controller instance
// Fragment required from "sap/ui/core/Fragment"
onOpenDialog: async function() {
  let dialog = this.byId("helloDialog");
  if (!dialog) {
    dialog = await this.getOwnerComponent().runAsOwner(() => Fragment.load({
      id: this.getView().getId(),
      name: "webapp.view.HelloDialog",
      controller: this,
    }));
    this.getView().addDependent(dialog);
  }
  dialog.open();
},
```

The old factory function `sap.ui.xmlfragment` is deprecated and fetches the `*.fragment.xml` file synchronously.

That being said, **if the app is targeting abandoned browsers such as the Internet Explorer, `async`‑`await` should be avoided completely.** `Promise` or `then`-able functions work in IE11 only because UI5 comes with a polyfill that gets applied if the `Promise` is not already natively or fully supported. ******

---

***** ... **if** the project is based on UI5 Tooling. See the newly introduced sections "Asynchronous Factory Function" and "Event Handler Registration" from the topic [**ECMAScript Support**](https://sdk.openui5.org/nightly/#/topic/0cb44d7a147640a0890cefa5fd7c7f8e) in UI5.

****** [IE11 is no longer supported.](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/74b59efa0eef48988d3b716bd0ecc933) The polyfill is also removed accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Refactoring that is pretty easy, all you need to do in addition is flagging the method you're calling it from as `async`, which is really the only change you need to make.

The biggest potential issue you'll have is [browser support](https://caniuse.com/?search=await), if you don't run your codebase through a tool like Babel. The biggest hurdle is IE 11, which many enterprise customers still use.

```
onFragmentLoad: async function(oEvent) {
  const oDialog = await Fragment.load({
    controller: this,
    id: this.getView().getId(),
    name: "webapp.view.HelloDialog"
  });

  this.getView().addDependent(oDialog);
}
```